# Member function pointer point to method of another object

Tags: c++, class, function, object, pointers

Is it possible to have a member function pointer of an object point to a method of another object? If so, please give an example.

Comment: Can we have some context? why do you want to achieve that?

Comment: Another object of the same type, or an object of a different type?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to have a member function pointer of an object point to a method of another object?

Yes.

> If so, please give an example.

I'll give you two.

```
struct A {
 void f() {}
};
struct B {
 void (A::*p)();
};

int main () {
 A a;
 B b;
 b.p = &A::f;
 (a.*b.p)();

 A* pA = &a;
 B* pB = &b;
 (pA->*pB->p)();
}
```